# Android : unresolved packages and class

Tags: android, class, package

in my AndroidManifest.xml, my receiver, service and activities are not found,

it should find `en.company.android.name.myclass`

however it says my packages(en, company, android, name) are unresolved, and so is the class inside of it.

here is the structure that it should find :

[image]

exemple in my AndroidManifest :

```
<receiver android:name="en.company.android.name.SimpleWakefulReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
```

Comment: did you try cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: How to achieve this in Android Studio 2.2 ? Invalidate and restart ? if so yes, if it's something else, nope

Comment: seems like purely not imported

Comment: Try clean and rebuild.. Check your project file structure, if it is Android

Comment: Just go to `Build -> Rebuild Project`.

Comment: there is not such thing in my Build menu

Answer (score 4):

go to project file location, and delete build folder, reopen you project, it work for me;

Answer (score 0):

step1. File--> close the project from android studio.
step2. Go to project folder delete .idea folder.
step3. Open android studio and open project from gradle.

The project will be rebuilt and it will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your functional directory is not correct and you can not find the build directory. You can do this:

1. If it is eclipse you can rebuild a new android project your java lowest level package copied to the new package
2. If android studio is simple, the path to src in gradle points to the underlying package, like this

   android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
         buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
          ......
         sourceSets {
             main { 
                  manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                  java.srcDirs = ['src/java']
                   ......
               }
             ......
           }
     }

Answer (score 0):

For me I had recently changed a typo in my package name/file folder and after that my activities could not be found. Thought I'd fixed it everywhere but I'd missed fixing it in my .idea/workspace.xml ... once I fixed it there I restarted android studio did a clean and build and then I was up and running again.